# Send span value to php script using post

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I am trying to send data from form to the mail using php script.
My problem is that i have span which is populated by javascript, but value of this span is not being sent using post function.

```
QtyA = 0;
PrcA = 15;
document.getElementById("product1").innerHTML = PrcA;

<form method="POST" action="form-to-email.php" name="ofrm">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="550" id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td width="250">Product1</td>
            <td align="center" width="100">
            <input type="text" name="qtyA" size="5" tabindex="5" onchange="calculate()"/></td>
            <td align="right" width="60"><span id="product1" name="PrcA"/></span></td>
            <td align="right" width="140">
            <input type="text" name="totalA" size="12" tabindex="99" onchange="calculate()"/></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

i tried to replace span with

```
   <input type="text" name="PrcA" id="product1" size="5" tabindex="5" onchange="calculate()"/>
```

but input field is not populated by the javascript

php

```
.....

    $qtyA = $_POST['qtyA'];
    $PrcA = $_POST['PrcA'];
    ...
    $email_body = "$qtyA $PrcA".
```

variable $QtyA is sent, but $PrcA is not

thanks

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the `<table>` tag inside the form element...

Comment: thanks for the note, i assume i will try to change this to clean css in the future

Comment: also, you can always call `var_dump($_POST)` if your doing testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the value in an hidden field also.

Try this:

```
QtyA = 0;
PrcA = 15;
document.getElementById("product1").innerHTML = PrcA;
document.getElementById("PrcA").value = PrcA;

<form method="POST" action="form-to-email.php" name="ofrm">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="PrcA" id="PrcA" />

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="550" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td width="250">Product1</td>
        <td align="center" width="100">
        <input type="text" name="qtyA" size="5" tabindex="5" onchange="calculate()"/></td>
        <td align="right" width="60"><span id="product1" name="PrcA"  /></span></td>
        <td align="right" width="140">
        <input type="text" name="totalA" size="12" tabindex="99" onchange="calculate()"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `<input type="hidden" value="" name="PrcA" />` be `<input type="hidden" value="" id="PrcA" />` instead?

Comment: name attribute is needed as when the form will be submitted the post elements passes the name of the elements not the id